# How can I visualize subset of a network in Cytoscape?

Tags: expression, graph-theory, cytoscape

I created a network using separate node and edge files generated from WGCNA. The network has 381 nodes and over 20K edges. I would like to learn how to subset the giant network that zoom in to one gene (node) which is the gene of my interest and other connected nodes that have similar expression to the gene of interest?

Thank you!
Abel

I tried to filter based on column value such as weight, but I ended up not getting what I want.

Comment: Your title mention 'subset' so maybe you want to extract just one node plus the nodes directly connected to it?  Please provide details of what you actually want to do - a small example always helps.

Comment: @ravenspoint, thank you for your response! By "plotting a network", I meant visualizing the subset network. Here is the details of what I want to do: I imported a node and edge file from WGCNA into Cytoscape and created this giant network, 381 nodes and thousands of edges. I am interested in visualizing all genes that show similar expression to the selected gene based on degree and number of edges. I am very happy to show you what I am trying to achieve via web-conferencing if that you would  be willing. Thank you!

Comment: "degree, one of the columns that I get when analyzing the network in Cytoscape, is the node degree distribution. https://med.bioinf.mpi-inf.mpg.de/netanalyzer/help/2.7/index.html#complex

Comment: Node degree distribution refers to the number of other nodes each node is connected to. This value is generated by clicking on "Tools" -> Analyze Network in Cytoscape. Sorry if I was not able to well describe my issues.

Comment: I have updated the question and wanted to see if that makes sense now. @ravenspoint Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a particular subset of a large graph containing only nodes 'of interest' is usually straightforward.  To answer in detail, we need details of how you define a node of interest.

In general:

- LOOP over nodes

  - IF node is 'interesting'

    - Copy node to subset
- LOOP over every pair of nodes in subset

  - IF node pair is linked in original graph

    - Copy link to subset

I am guessing that you have already tried something like this.  If it doesn't work then you may have a bug in your code.  We cannot help with that without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Cytoscape, I'd to this in two steps:

1. Select your starting gene of interest, then select first neighbors (F6), and make subnetwork.
2. Filter your subnetwork based on expression thresholds.

Comment: You can also script these steps in R or Python, if that's your jam. See RCy3 and py4cytoscape libs.